# Unusual designs inside of laptop LCD

Tags: laptop, lcd, dell-latitude, defective-hardware

Since last few days, I am noticing an unusual line like design in my laptop screen. If seen from front side, the line doesn't appear, but seen from upside, it is visible.

[This image is showing the front view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s30Tg.jpg)

[This is another image showing the defect when observed from upside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbBiA.jpg)

What kind of defect is it ? Will it cause any problems ?

Comment: That looks like a child has drawn on the screen thinking it's a tablet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's almost certainly not a crack, which is a good thing, but it is some sort of minor damage, likely from pressure from a tipped object pressed against the screen, such as a pen or stylus.

It should not result in further degradation if this is the case, but it is unlikely to go away either.

Comment: Could it be caused by an insect ? I sometimes see some small insects inside the screen.

Comment: That's another possibile explanation.